# Databinding not updating when changing through Storyboards?

Tags: c#, wpf, binding, storyboard

I have a instance of the class **MyBool** with a property of **IsTrue** stored as a *StaticResource*. And I also have a CheckBox with its IsChecked property binded to the instance of the class.

```
{Binding IsTrue, Mode=TwoWay, Source={StaticResource MyBoolInstance}}
```

It works fine. If I change the check property on the CheckBox, the instance of **MyBool** updates as well, and vice-versa.

However, if I manipulate the IsChecked property of the CheckBox **through** a StoryBoard

```
<Storyboard x:Key="ColourToggle">  
  <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames 
        Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked"  
        Storyboard.TargetName="ThisCheckBox">  
    <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">  
      <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>  
          <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>  
      </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>  
    </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>  
  </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>  
</Storyboard>
```

The property **IsTrue** of the instance of **MyBool** doesn't update!

Any suggestions or work-arounds?

Comment: But the `ThisCheckBox.IsChecked` property does change? What are you actually trying to achieve by using the `Storyboard`?

Comment: Yeah it does. My way of thinking is kinda faulty, I'm trying to use a storyboard to change the IsChecked property of the CheckBox, hoping it would also change the binded object.

Comment: If you set `IsChecked` with animation, you override your binding. You should change binding source, not the CheckBox itself.

Comment: I see now :D How do you update the binding source in XAML?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Here is an example that fully reproduces your problem:

```
<StackPanel>
    <StackPanel.Resources>
        <l:MyBool x:Key="MyBool" IsTrue="False" />
    </StackPanel.Resources>
    <CheckBox x:Name="myCheckBox"
              Content="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=Self}, Path=IsChecked}"
              IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBool}, Path=IsTrue, Mode=TwoWay}"
              HorizontalAlignment="Center"
              VerticalAlignment="Top">
        <CheckBox.Triggers>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseEnter">
                <BeginStoryboard  x:Name="isCheckedBeginStoryboard">
                    <Storyboard>
                        <ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames Storyboard.TargetProperty="IsChecked">
                            <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame KeyTime="0">
                                <DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                                    <System:Boolean>True</System:Boolean>
                                </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame.Value>
                            </DiscreteObjectKeyFrame>
                        </ObjectAnimationUsingKeyFrames>
                    </Storyboard>
                </BeginStoryboard>
            </EventTrigger>
            <EventTrigger RoutedEvent="UIElement.MouseLeave">
                <StopStoryboard BeginStoryboardName="isCheckedBeginStoryboard" />
            </EventTrigger>
        </CheckBox.Triggers>
    </CheckBox>
    <CheckBox Content="Also two way binding to MyBool.IsTrue no animation" IsChecked="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBool}, Path=IsTrue}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding Source={StaticResource MyBool}, Path=IsTrue, StringFormat={}MyBool.IsTrue: {0}}" />
    <TextBlock Text="{Binding ElementName=myCheckBox, Path=IsChecked, StringFormat={}myCheckBox.IsChecked: {0}}" />
</StackPanel>
```

Where `MyBool` is a simple class that also implements `INotifyPropertyChanged`:

```
public class MyBool : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private bool _isTrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return _isTrue; }
        set
        {
            if (_isTrue != value)
            {
                _isTrue = value;
                NotifyPropertyChanged("IsTrue");
            }
        }
    }

    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private void NotifyPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
            PropertyChanged.Invoke(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
    }
}
```

As you can see from running this, when the animation is active your `StaticResource` is not being updated - when the animation is NOT active it is. This happens since when the animation runs WPF provides a new value for the `IsChecked` property (as defined by your `Storyboard`). This effectively clobbers the old value - the two-way `Binding` to the `StaticResource`. Once the animation finishes and is stopped, WPF will restore the old value of `IsChecked` back to the original binding expression, hence your resource `MyBool` will continue to receive updates.

A great article on `DependencyProperty` value precedence can be found here:

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms743230.aspx

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

The problem is in *binding*, and not in UI.
You can try set IsChecked in code-behind `ThisCheckBox.IsChecked = true;` and this will be ignored if you have binding in XAML!

XAML:

```
<Window x:Class="WpfApplication3.Window1"
xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
Title="Window1" Height="300" Width="300">
<Grid>
    <CheckBox x:Name="ThisCheckBox" IsChecked="{Binding IsTrue}" />
</Grid>
```

code:

```
public partial class Window1 : Window
{
    public Window1()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        this.DataContext = new CData();

        ThisCheckBox.ClearValue(CheckBox.IsCheckedProperty);
        //next will work only after clear binding
        ThisCheckBox.IsChecked = true;
    }
}

public class CData : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    private bool _isTrue;
    public bool IsTrue
    {
        get { return _isTrue; }
        set
        {
            if (_isTrue != value)
            {
                _isTrue = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(new PropertyChangedEventArgs("IsTrue"));
            }
        }
    }

    protected virtual void OnPropertyChanged(PropertyChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        PropertyChangedEventHandler handler = PropertyChanged;
        if (handler != null)
        {
            handler(this, e);
        }
    }
}
```